# Puzzle deslizante c++ . No funciona la función de comprobar si el juego ha terminado

Tags: c++

Quiero crear un proyecto de un puzzle deslizante, el problema esta en que cuando le meto la función "Fin" al programa para comprobar si han llegado ya al final, el programa deja de funcionar.
Si la quito, funciona, pero hay fichas, que cuando pido moverlas no me deja, se buggea.
El programa está hecho con una matriz dinámica.

**Primero, este es el programa principal.**

```
#include "funciones.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int **matriz; 
    int nfilas, ncolumnas, FichaMover;
    bool final = false;
    
    cout << "Dime de cuantas filas quieres la matriz: ";
    cin >> nfilas;
    cout << "Dime cuantas columnas quieres en la matriz: ";
    cin >> ncolumnas;
    
    matriz = new int* [nfilas];
    for (int i=0;i<nfilas;i++)
    {
        matriz[i]= new int[ncolumnas];  
    }
    
    RellenaMatriz (matriz, nfilas, ncolumnas);
    
    do
    {
        DibujaTablero(matriz, nfilas, ncolumnas);
        cout << "Dime la ficha que desea mover: ";
        cin >> FichaMover;
        MueveFicha(matriz, nfilas, ncolumnas, FichaMover);
        final = finPartida (matriz, nfilas, ncolumnas);

    }
    while ((final == false) && (FichaMover != 0));

    for (int i=0;i<nfilas;i++)
    {
        delete []matriz[i];
    }
        
    delete [] matriz;
    
    return 0;   
}
```

**Y aqui estan todas las funciones**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void DibujaTablero(int **tablero, int numfils, int numcols) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    system("cls"); 
    cout <<"PUZZLE DESLIZANTE" << endl << endl; 
    for(i = 0; i < numfils; i ++ ) 
    { 
        for(j = 0; j < numcols; j ++ ) 
        { 
        cout << " --"; 
        } 
        cout << endl; 
        for(j = 0; j < numcols; j ++ ) 
        {    
            cout << "|"; 
            cout.width(2); 
            if ( tablero[i][j] != 0 ) 
                cout << tablero[i][j]; 
            else 
             cout << " "; 
        } 
        cout << "|" << endl; 
    } 
     
     for(j = 0; j < numcols; j ++ ) 
    { 
        cout << " --"; 
    } 
    cout << endl << endl; 
    
    return; 
}

void RellenaMatriz (int **matriz, int nfilas, int ncolumnas)
{
    int ficha = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nfilas; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<ncolumnas; j++)
        {
            matriz[i][j] = ficha;
            ficha ++;
        }
    }
}

void MueveFicha (int **matriz, int nfilas, int ncolumnas, int FichaMover)
{
    for (int i=0; i<nfilas; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<ncolumnas; j++)
        {
            if (matriz[i][j] == FichaMover)
            {
                if (matriz[i+1][j]==0)
                {
                    matriz[i+1][j] = FichaMover;
                    matriz[i][j] =0;    
                }
                if (matriz[i-1][j]==0)
                {
                    matriz[i-1][j] = FichaMover;
                    matriz[i][j] =0;
                }
                if (matriz[i][j+1]==0)
                {
                    matriz[i][j+1] = FichaMover;
                    matriz[i][j] =0;
                }
                if (matriz[i][j-1]==0)
                {
                    matriz[i][j-1] = FichaMover;
                    matriz[i][j] =0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

bool finPartida (int **matriz, int nfilas, int ncolumnas )
{
    bool fin = false;
    int contador = 0;
    int n = 1;  
    
    if (matriz[nfilas][ncolumnas]==0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<nfilas; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<ncolumnas; j++)
            {
                if (matriz[i][j] == n)
                {
                    contador++;
                }
                n++;
            }
        }
        if (contador == (nfilas*ncolumnas)-1)
        {
            fin = true;
        }
    }   
    
    return fin;
}
```

Para ganar el usuario tiene que dejar todos los números ordenados y el espacio (representado como un 0 en el programa) abajo a la derecha del todo.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda o cualquier consejo ya que llevo bastantes horas con esto y al final me va a explotar la cabeza.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matriz[nfilas][ncolumnas]==0)
```

Si declaras una matriz de tamaño `nfilas`, `ncolumnas`, la última posición del array no es `[nfilas][ncolumnas]`, sino `[nfilas-1][ncolumnas-1]`. Recuerda que el primer índice es el 0, no el 1.

La posición `[nfilas][ncolumnas]` no pertenece al array, sino a otra variable (o puede ser memoria sin asignar). El valor que recuperes en esa posición no puedes usarlo para nada.